# Date interval sql syntax

Tags: sql, date, prestashop-1.7

I make this sql query in prestashop 1.7 but the date interval doesn't work.

My code is :

```
$todays =date("Y-m-d");
$t_days=date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-30 days'));

$id_clientee=$this->context->customer->id;

$spent_month  = Db::getInstance()->getValue(
        'SELECT SUM(total_paid_real) AS sum FROM ' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'orders WHERE 

          date_add BETWEEN "'.pSQL($t_days).' 00:00:00" AND "'.pSQL($todays).' 23:59:59"
          AND id_customer = ' . (int)$id_clientee . ' 
         AND (current_state = 5 or current_state = 4 )
         ');

$spesaaaa=(int)$spent_month;
```

`date_add` format on DB is : `2017-05-29 13:33:13 Type: datetime`

Why is `date_add1 interval not working?

Comment: Have you check the query before getting the value? Also, is $id_clientee correct?

Comment: Yes , without  date_add condition the query work fine .

Comment: It works on my side. Try to change the condition to WHERE date_add >= "'.pSQL($t_days).' 00:00:00" AND  date_add <= "'.pSQL($todays).' 23:59:59" ...

Comment: Yesss , this work also for me thanks !

Comment: I am used to seeing date literal strings put in single quotes not double quotes.